# Colspan doesn't work with <td> width set? (IE7)

Tags: html, html-table

I can't get colspan to work when I use a fixed width (IE 7)? Why?!

Sample Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .inputGroup td
    { width:250px; }    
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table class="inputGroup">
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">This should span two columns but it doesnt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Help anybody? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it does, but you've limited the width. If you want, try creating another class called '.doubleSpanInputGroup' or something with width 500 and set that class onto the spanning column.

eg.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .inputGroup td
    { width:250px; }   
    .inputGroup td.doubleInputGroup
    { width:500px; } 
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table class="inputGroup">
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="doubleInputGroup">This should span two columns but it doesnt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: made the new style more hierarchical

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks, sometimes you just don't see what's right in front of you.

Comment: yeah no probs, easy mistake. Please make sure you use my revised version above as the first pass had a small problem :) woops.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the rule apply to `tr` instead of `td` and make the width 500px instead, as such:

```
.inputGroup tr { width: 500px; }
```

The problem you're having is because you've set a limit on the `td` to be at most 250px wide, so the browser is simply following your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

in general manner :

```
table tr:first-child td:first-child{ width:86px; }
```

if this is the only width all first column take this width and colspan in ie7 will work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set the width of the colspan cells to auto, seemed to work fine in IE7/8/9

```
.yourColSpanTD { width: auto !important; }
```